# Java rest ws : javax.net.ssl.SSLException connection reset

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

I have `java rest web service`. When I call that service from client application and if WS takes **more than 5 minutes then request** is getting terminated by throwing below error.

> I/O Error  on POST request for  WS_URL connection reset; nested
> exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException.

I believe it web service who is resting the request. I am using tomcat and I don't see any configuration which terminates request in 5 minutes.

I would appreciate help on this.

Comment: Are you using AWS? I ask because I had this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605720/intermittent-java-io-ioexception-connection-reset-not-connection-reset-by-peer/63659148#63659148 If not, try putting some breakpoints in `jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl`.

Comment: @RobertBain, No we are not using AWS. Thanks... let me check that

Comment: does the client connect through a proxy?